# Why do we say 'aim high' instead of 'aim highly'?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I know we don't say 'aim highly', but I don't know how to exaplain in grammatical terms. Is 'aim high' an idiom? Is 'high' an adverb? If it is, then why can't we say 'aim highly'?

Comment: Because we think different.

Comment: It's probably good to know that the 'ly' ending is falling out of use.  A lot of people still judge statements like "it performed phenomenal" as incorrect (myself included) but I hear this kind of thing pretty regular(ly).

Comment: I still can't accept people saying 'eat healthy' instead of 'eat healthily'.

Answer (score 25):

"Aim high" isn't telling you *in what manner* to aim, but *where* to aim.  "Aim high, above the basket, in order to have the basketball reach the basket."  "Aim carefully" would be telling you *how* to aim.

Comment: Can you also add something about why "highly" would be incorrect?

Comment: @gotube: The first sentence addresses this point. It does so tersely but sufficiently for the answer to be informative.

Answer (score 12):

It's not an idiom, it's just a directional phrase, similar to "turn left", "go West", or "look up". Here, "high" is indeed an adverb, acting as a direction; you can replace it with "aim low", "aim left", "aim down", "aim straight ahead", etc.

It is certainly not equivalent to "aim highly", which doesn't have a clear meaning to my native ears, but would sound like a confused attempt at something like "aim well".

I don't think it's particularly related to the construction "think big", as the other answer suggests. You can say "think X" for almost any adjective or noun X, as a plea to change one's mental frame of reference: "think positive", "think dollars, not cents", "think science, not magic", etc. That is more idiomatic.

Comment: Even if not related to "think big", it's related to "grow big". Which, in spite what Trump might think, would never be "grow bigly".   Or, let's use another word: "grow large" rather than "grow largely".

Comment: *Aim big/ aim local/ aim global* those are all other *aim* + adjective combinations. Aim takes an adjective not an adverb in those examples. And as described by James K, *high* is an adjective not an adverb in OP's example too.

Comment: The latter paragraph is confusing two very different constructions of "think X". "Big" refers to _the manner of thinking_, but the other examples are different. "Positive" is ambiguous between how you think (think in a positive manner) and what you think about (think of positive things). "Dollars" and "science" fall squarely in the category of what you think about, not the manner in which you think. These cannot be lumped into one category. There is a reason why it's "think big" and not "think bigly", but it not for the reason that this answer attempts to give.

Answer (score 9):

It's idiomatic, one of a family of idioms including "think big", "act bold" and (perhaps) "try hard", in which the word "high/big/hard" serves figuratively in place of a prepositional or noun phrase.  "Aim high" can be understood as "Aim for the high thing".  Due to its idiomatic nature, you can't mix up the adjectives and expect to get an idiomatic expression. "Think high" or "aim bold" don't mean much (but "act big" is possible).

Comment: Also, the adverb _highly_ means _very, to a high degree_ not _towards a high position_.

Comment: I think "act bold" is more of a linking phrase, like "be bold", not very like "think big" or "try hard".

Comment: Prezackerly it's an adjective, which is why you can modify it with *very* and not *right* or *straight*. There's a few other adjectives that can take part in the *aim* + [adjective] construction. Here's a few from COCA: *aim big/ aim small/ aim true/ aim sure/ aim global/ aim wide*.